# how to write derivative of function

Tags: python, sympy

i have to write an equation using python.
The equation is `f(x)=(3+2x)e-x`
and calculate `f'(x)` for `x=2` and `f'(x)=limit(i->0){[f(x+i)-f(x-i)]/2i}` for `i= 10^-n` where `n=2, 3, 4` and then integrate it.
For this question i tried program in python

```
import math
from math import exp
import sympy as sp
x = sp.Symbol('x')
sp.diff((3+2*x)*math.exp(-x),x)
from scipy.misc import derivative
def f(x):
    return (3+2*x)*math.exp(-x)
def d(x):
    return derivative (f,x)
def d(x):
    h=1./1000.
    rise=f(x+h)-f(x-h)
    run=2*h
    slop = rise/run
    return slop
def integral(startingx, endingx, number of rectangles):
    width = (endingx-startingx)/number of rectangles
    runningsum = 0
    for i in range(number of rectangles):
        height = f(startingx + i*width)
        area= height*width
        runningSum += area
        return runningSum
print (f)
print (derivative(f,2))
print (integral)
```

Comment: `sympy` won't differentiate an ordinary Python function; you have to define a `sympy` object that *represents* the mathematical function.

Comment: Clarify: is your goal to do these calculations numerically, or to do them symbolically? You're using `sympy` in some places, but you're defining numerical derivatives and integrals in others.

Comment: What do you mean by "integrate it"? What exactly do you want to integrate?

Comment: At the places you're using sympy, you can't use `math.exp` nor `scipy.derivative`.

Comment: Josh Karpel, my goal is to do the derivative and integrate the function by numerical method.

Answer (score 0):

The following sympy code calculates the derivative and the integral symbolically. Note that you can't use functions from Python's math library nor other libraries such as scipy and numpy inside the symbolic calculations. Sympy has a function `lambdify()` if you need to generate a function for numerical calculations. Sympy's `subs` command can replace a variable with a specific value. `simplify()` can be useful to write formulas in a simpler form.

```py
import sympy as sp
x = sp.Symbol('x')

def f(x):
    return (3+2*x)*sp.exp(-x)

def d(x):
    return sp.diff(f(x), x)

def derivative_via_formula(x, eps):
    return (f(x + eps) - f(x - eps)) / (2 * eps)

print ("f(x):", f(x))
print ("derivative:", d(x).simplify())
print ("derivative at x=2 :", d(x).subs(x, 2).simplify())
print ("derivative at x=2 evaluated:", d(x).subs(x, 2).evalf())
print ("the integral of f(x):", sp.integrate(f(x)).simplify())
for n in range(2,5):
    eps = 10**(-n)
    print("derivative_via_formula, eps=10^-%d:" % n, derivative_via_formula(2, eps))
```

Output:

```
f(x): (2*x + 3)*exp(-x)
derivative: -(2*x + 1)*exp(-x)
derivative at x=2 : -5*exp(-2)
derivative at x=2 evaluated: -0.676676416183063
the integral of f(x): -(2*x + 5)*exp(-x)
derivative_via_formula, eps=10^-2: -0.676678671737280
derivative_via_formula, eps=10^-3: -0.676676438738810
derivative_via_formula, eps=10^-4: -0.676676416409006
```

Comment: Was this answer helpful?